# How to sort JSON data using php getting data from mysql

Tags: php, json

Hello guys am trying to sort json data but i don't know how to do that. Need it for my android app in which i want to try short the data with ID. Thank you in advance.

```
 <?php

require "init.php";   // This file provide the connetion 


header('Content-type:application/json');

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from post_s order ('post_id DESC')");

$rows= array();

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows[] = array('post_id'=>$row['post_id'],'user_id'=>$row['user_id'],'user_name'=>$row['user_name'],'post_title'=>$row['post_title'],'likes'=>$row['likes'],'post_cat'=>$row['post_cat'],'post_time'=>$row['post_time']);

}


if (json_encode($rows) == '[]') 

    echo "No new posts found !! ";

    else echo json_encode(array("post"=>$rows));


?>
```

This file will provide the json output like

```
{
 "post":
    [
       {
         "post_id":"7001",
         "user_id":"1001",
         "user_name":"qwerty asdfg",
         "post_title":"check this post",
         "likes":"456",
         "post_cat":"ghghjg",
         "post_time":"45632"
       },
       {
         "post_id":"7002",
         "user_id":"0984",
         "user_name":"abcd efgh",
         "post_title":"hello guys perfect post",
         "likes":"123",
         "post_cat":"mobile",
         "post_time":"12345"
       }
    ]
}
```

But i need to output like

```
{
 "post":
    [
       {
         "post_id":"7002",
         "user_id":"0984",
         "user_name":"abcd efgh",
         "post_title":"hello guys perfect post",
         "likes":"123",
         "post_cat":"mobile",
         "post_time":"12345"
       },
       {
         "post_id":"7001",
         "user_id":"1001",
         "user_name":"qwerty asdfg",
         "post_title":"check this post",
         "likes":"456",
         "post_cat":"ghghjg",
         "post_time":"45632"
       }
    ]
}
```

Thanks again for help in advance

Comment: Read, decode, sort - which of the three is causing problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `usort`.

```
usort($rows, function($a, $b){
    return (((int) $a["post_id"]) > ((int) $b["post_id"])) ? 1 : 0;
});
```

Or use the `<=>` spaceship operator in PHP 7

Comment: `usort` accepts first argument by reference, so it modifies `$rows`. So add this before you encode and send `$rows`.